# Why does it return undefined? (Jquery xml parsing issue)

Tags: jquery, xml, arrays, parsing

I tried to populate a two dimensoinal array through parsing xml, but my function doesn't store the first items for some unknown reason. (So it stores [0][1] and [1][1] properly, but it does not store [0][0] and [0][1]);

The idea behind the array structure is:

```
first word-  >  first choice  ->[0][0]; 
first word  ->  second choice ->[0][1]; 
second word ->  first choice  ->[1][0];
... you can guess
```

It alerts everytime (just to check that counters are correct.)

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Page>
  <Word id = "0">
    <Choice id = "0">
     <text>First word - 1. choice</text>
    </Choice>
    <Choice id = "1">
     <text>First word - 2. choice</text>
    </Choice>
  </Word>
 <Word id= "1">
  <Choices>
    <Choice id = "0">
      <text>Second word - First choice</text>
    </Choice>
    <Choice id= "1">
     <text>Second word - Second Choice</text>
    </Choice>
  </Choices>
 </Word>
</Page>
```

The function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "xml.xml",
 dataType: "xml",
 success: parseXml2
  });
});

function parseXml2(xml) {

var myArray = [];
var a = 0;

$(xml).find("Word").each(function() {
    var i = $(this).attr("id");
    a = 0;

    $(this).find("Choice").each(function() {
        alert('I:' + i + 'A:' + a);
        alert('Id:' + $(this).attr("id") + $(this).text());
        myArray[i] = [];
        var text = $(this).text();
        myArray[i][a] = text;
        a++;
    });
});

alert(myArray[0][0]);

}

parseXml2(xml);​
```

The code can also be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3vBk6/3/).

Comment: In future please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should standalone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Comment: Ok, I've added my code! Will do so from now on everytime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you set `myArray[i] = [];` on each iteration. Set it in this loop `$(xml).find("Word").each(function() {` not the second one. vágod :D?

this should work:

```
$(xml).find("Word").each(function() {
    var i = $(this).attr("id");
    a = 0;
    myArray[i] = [];
    $(this).find("Choice").each(function() {
        alert('I:' + i + 'A:' + a);
        alert('Id:' + $(this).attr("id") + $(this).text());

        var text = $(this).text();
        myArray[i][a] = text;
        a++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! :D I missed the obvious again.. (köszi wazze! :D)

Comment: azért ez nem volt annyira obvious :D egy ideig elszarakodtam vele :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code lies in the `myArray[i] = [];` line.

With this line, you're redefining the array at every iteration.

One solution to overcome that would be to write

```
if(typeof(myArray[i]) === "undefined"){
    myArray[i] = [];
}
```

in order to ensure you're not writting it if it exists

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vBk6/5/)